# How to supress warning: Datetime with no tzinfo will be considered UTC?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone

I have the following code which am using to monitor Azure ADF pipeline runs. The code uses '**RunFilterParameters**' to apply a date range filter in extracting run results:

```
filter_params = RunFilterParameters(last_updated_after=datetime.now() - timedelta(1), last_updated_before=datetime.now() + timedelta(1))     
query_response = adf_client.activity_runs.query_by_pipeline_run(resource_group, adf_name, row.latest_runid,filter_params)
```

The above works ok, however it is throwing a warning:

```
Datetime with no tzinfo will be considered UTC
```

Not sure how to add timezone to this or just suppress the warning?
Please help.

Comment: if you work with UTC and you want "now" to be UTC, use `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`.

Comment: Thanks. The above worked perfectly. Perhaps you want to add it as an answer so I can accept it to help others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"no tzinfo" means that [naive datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects) is used, i.e. datetime with no defined time zone. Since Python assumes local time by default for naive datetime, this can cause unexpected behavior.

In the code example given in the question, you can create an aware datetime object (with tz specified to be UTC) like

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
# and use
datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

If you need to use another time zone than UTC, have a look at [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) (Python 3.9+ standard library).